# Error when using custom model in TensorFlow Android Camera Demo

Tags: android, c++, tensorflow

I trained a model with `input_shape=[125,100,100,1]` to predict 8 floats. I changed [these options](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/TensorFlowImageListener.java#L50-L59) on the demo to fit with my model's settings.

Then I added another option to the batch size

```
private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 125;
```

In [the C++ side](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/jni/tensorflow_inference_jni.cc), I've printed some debug information to see the shape of my tensors:

```
LOG (INFO)  << "input node: "  << input_tensors[0].first << ", "
          << "input shape: " << input_tensors[0].second.shape().DebugString();
```

> tensorflow_inference_jni.cc:198 input node: input_node, input shape:
>   [125,100,100,1]

But the application crashes just when it calls the [`vars->session->Run()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/jni/tensorflow_inference_jni.cc#L192) function

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 16574 (InferenceThread)
```

Now if I set `BATCH_SIZE = 1` (always working with the model trained with 125 of batch size] the application don't crash, but it returns this error:

```
E/native: tensorflow_inference_jni.cc:213 Error during inference: Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 8 values, but the requested shape has 1000
[[Node: output_node = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](fullyconnected2_1/BiasAdd, output_node/shape)]]
```

The requested shape 1000 in this error is num_output * batch_size I guess (8 * 125).

[image]

did I miss something ?

Comment: Are you executing the inference on the main thread?

Comment: no, there is a [background thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6b1d4fd8090d44d20fdadabf06f1a9b178c3d80c/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/CameraConnectionFragment.java#L428) for inference

Answer (score 0):

I've hardcoded the batch size on the training so I had to feed the model with tensors of shape `[125,100,100,1]`. This is a little too much for a mobile, so Android decides to kill the application.

Works perfectly when I retrained a model with `batch_size = 1`